# How can I omit the property names of my json and just display the values?

Tags: javascript, json, google-docs, google-docs-api

I wrote a small api to pull nutrition info from public diaries on MyFitnessPal. I'm pulling this information into a Google Sheet using the ImportJSON.gs found here: https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

What I get is a two row result:

```
Calories    Protein Fat Carbs
2458        196     82  234
```

My returned json looks like this:

```
{"Calories":"1738","Protein":"140","Fat":"78","Carbs":"119"}
```

I want just the numbers and not the property names. I don't want to alter the json to just return a string array, but since this is for personal usage, I will if necessary! Any ideas?

Comment: Unless MyFitnessPal allow you to change the query to omit the keys off the values then you'll have to remove them yourself. Additionally, it is not best practice to simply return data without keys as it doesn't give developers data context. For example if you received "140, 140, 140", how would you know what the values were?

Comment: MyFitnessPal doesn't have a public API, I'm screen scraping in my own created API. Since this is for a personal use in a private Google Sheet, I'd know which order they are in. However, I'd rather NOT change my api to only return the data without keys. I was looking for a way for Google Sheets and the ImportJSON script to simply display the values without property names. If that is simply not possible, I'll just have to return the data, maybe in a separately routed Get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var o = {"Calories":"1738","Protein":"140","Fat":"78","Carbs":"119"}
var values = values(o); //gives you an array of values
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you know how to retrieve the JSON.  Just loop through the object:

```
function convert() {
  var myJson = {"Calories":"1738","Protein":"140","Fat":"78","Carbs":"119"};
  var thisKey;
  var thisValue;
  var newArray = [];

  for (var key in myJson) {
    thisKey = key;  
    thisValue = myJson[thisKey];
    newArray.push(thisValue);
  };

  return newArray;
};
```

This creates an array of just the values.

returns:  [1738, 140, 78, 119]

Answer (score 0):

Simply push each value into a new array:

```
var values = [];
for (var i in myJson){
    values.push(myJson[i])
}
```